# CodeIgniter 1.7.2 POST Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am sending a form via `POST` method on CodeIgniter 1.7.2 yet when I `var_dump($_SERVER)` on the receiving method on the controller the `REQUEST_METHOD` is `GET`, any clue why? feels like an htaccess issue.

Comment: R u using method attribute in form tag?

Comment: Or are u using CI FORM CLASS?

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: form_open(), thus CI FORM class.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to `POST`

CodeIgniter

```
echo form_open('email/send');
```

Html form

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/email/send" />
```

Using ajax

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: success,
   dataType: dataType
});
```

You could use CodeIgniter `input`

```
$this->input->post('somethig');
```